# Forward IIS NTLM Authentication Inside Tomcat to Another Service

Tags: java, tomcat, iis, ntlm, ajp

I have an architecture like the following one:

**IIS(Windows Authentication Enabled) -> AJP Connector -> Tomcat**

AJP Connector in server.xml is configured with tomcatAuthorization = true and tomcatAuthentication = false

Inside tomcat, I am able to get all user information from NTLM (roles, username, domain, etc) and everything works fine from that point of view.

Now I have the necessity to call inside tomcat, another service that uses NTLM as well. So the new architecture will be:

**IIS(Windows Authentication Enabled) -> AJP Connector -> Tomcat -> external NTLM Web Service**

My aim is to forward the NTLM information that Tomcat receives from IIS, to the external NTLM WS in order to makes the call by the original user, without ask user to provide again the Windows Credentials and use, inside Tomcat ,the response from that WS.

Is that any way (using e.g. Apache HTTP Client) to reuse the "NTLM" Principal obtained by IIS to perform this kind of HTTP Request?

Thanks all!